# How to prevent serializer to enclose string with CDATA

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap

I am looking for a way to stop the Serializer in my Web API to enclose a String with a CDATA Tag. My Soap Service uses a escaped String field in the body to hold a xml Doc. The remote SoapService does not understand and handle CDATA enclosed String so i need to find a way to tell it either not to enclose it or find a way to remove it before its send.

```
`<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("AuthHeaderValue"), System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("tMLHeaderValue"),System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace:="java:lsr.webservice.wisor.com", ResponseNamespace:="java:lsr.webservice.wisor.com", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)>  _

Public Function processSyncRequest(ByVal [string] As String) As <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("response")> String
Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("processSyncRequest", New Object() {[string]})
Return CType(results(0),String)
End Function`
```

which creates this body with the CDATA

```
<string xmlns=""><![CDATA[&lt;localserviceporequest xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns:xsd=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://www.synchronoss.com/lsr/FTR_PO&quot;&gt;
&lt;addressvalidation&gt;
&lt;ccna&gt;XD1&lt;/ccna&gt;
&lt;txnum /&gt;
&lt;dtsent /&gt;
&lt;tos /&gt;
&lt;ctval /&gt;
&lt;location&gt;
  &lt;route /&gt;
  &lt;aft&gt;N&lt;/aft&gt;
  &lt;sano&gt;1100&lt;/sano&gt;
  &lt;sasf /&gt;
  &lt;sasd&gt;S&lt;/sasd&gt;
  &lt;sasn&gt;Coast&lt;/sasn&gt;
  &lt;sath&gt;Hwy&lt;/sath&gt;
  &lt;sass /&gt;
  &lt;city&gt;Beach&lt;/city&gt;
  &lt;state&gt;CA&lt;/state&gt;
  &lt;zip&gt;90000&lt;/zip&gt;
&lt;/location&gt;
&lt;/addressvalidation&gt;
&lt;/localserviceporequest&gt;]]></string>
```

Comment: Not enough information. What is calling this code? The obvious answer is "don't return it as a string" but we have no way of knowing what the rest of your service code will accept instead.

Comment: I am calling the code myself and there is no other way then string as that's the requirement imposed by trading partner. But it seems i might have found the source of issue. As i am debugging the service via SoapUi i cam across some posts which mention that the default behavior of SoapUi is to ad the CData Tag

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully my findings will help someone else not wasting a ton of time on this issue. My problem was two fold. For one i used a the **SecurityElement.Escape(myString)** in my code to make sure my string is save. Then when i past the string to my soap call the system tried to clean it up again which seems to be a default behavior which caused the "<" to turn int a &lt which the far end could not understand and trew an error. The second issue was the presence of the CDATA tag in my string which i thought was the source of my issue but it turns out it really wasn't part of sting but ReadyAPI showed it in the XML view. After i went to raw i saw it wasn't there.